# subsetting a range between two percentages (R)

Tags: r, range, subset, percentage

I have a numeric vector consisting of 150 observations ranging from -217544 to 319842.
I would like to create a subset based on a range of percentages. In other words I would like to subset everything between 30% and 70%.

for instance:

```
bm.sort <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ,10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
```

I would like for the code to select the middle 40% (7 to 14).

I have so far tried the code

```
bm.m <- subset(bm.sort, bm.sort >= quantile(bm.sort, 0.3 %between% bm.sort <= quantile(bm.sort, 0.7)))
```

and

```
bm.m <- subset(bm.sort, bm.sort >= quantile(bm.sort, 0.3 | bm.sort <= quantile(bm.sort, 0.7)))
```

However when I use this code I only receive one observation instead of the range of 60 observations that i should receive.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please provide example data to make your code reproducible.

Comment: You have a syntax error in your code. `bm.m <- subset(bm.sort, bm.sort >= quantile(bm.sort, 0.3) | bm.sort <= quantile(bm.sort, 0.7))`

Comment: sorry about that, I have updated the code and and example

Comment: try `subset(bm.sort, bm.sort >= quantile(bm.sort, 0.3) & bm.sort <= quantile(bm.sort, 0.7))`

Comment: When I use & instead of | I get everything above 70%

Comment: Try doing this with the data frame method instead of subset. Like so: `bm.b <- bm.sort["YOUR BOOLEAN EXPRESSION HERE", ]` Sometimes things don't work well with the `subset` function as it is not meant to be used in line, but only for convenience.

Comment: When using     bm.m <- bm.sort[EXPRESSION]    I get the exact same result like when I use subset.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out (missing ")" ), sorry for taking up your time unnecessarily.

Thank you for all the help.